# Pythonic way to get some rows of a matrix

Tags: list, coding-style, filtering, python

I was thinking about a code that I wrote a few years ago in Python, at some point it had to get just some elements, by index, of a list of lists.

I remember I did something like this:

```
def getRows(m, row_indices):
    tmp = []
    for i in row_indices:
        tmp.append(m[i])
    return tmp
```

Now that I've learnt a little bit more since then, I'd use a list comprehension like this:

```
[m[i] for i in row_indices]
```

But I'm still wondering if there's an even more pythonic way to do it. Any ideas?

I would like to know also alternatives with numpy o any other array libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth looking at [NumPy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) for its slicing syntax. Scroll down in the linked page until you get to "Indexing, Slicing and Iterating".

Comment: seemed promising, but nothing like I was searching :(

Comment: in what way does numpy not fit your need?  to get a row you would just do M[i, :].

Comment: yeah, now I've tried and it works, but I didn't find it in the docs so I thought the feature was missing...

Comment: Hmmm... I stopped at section 3.5 and the interesting stuff was at section 4.3.1

Answer (score 4):

It's the clean an obvious way. So, I'd say it doesn't get more Pythonic than that.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there was a nicer way to pass a sequence of index between the accessor brackets or something like that :-/

Answer (score 2):

As  Curt said, it seems that Numpy is a good tool for this.  Here's an example,

```
from numpy import *

a = arange(16).reshape((4,4))
b = a[:, [1,2]]
c = a[[1,2], :]

print a
print b
print c
```

gives

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
[[ 1  2]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 9 10]
 [13 14]]
[[ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```