# How to pick certain elements of x-tuple returned by a function?

Tags: python, list, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I am a newbie to Python. Consider the function `str.partition()` which returns a 3-tuple. If I am interested in only elements 0 and 2 of this tuple, what is the best way to pick only certain elements out of such a tuple?

I can currently do either:

```
# Introduces "part1" variable, which is useless
(part0, part1, part2) = str.partition(' ')
```

Or:

```
# Multiple calls and statements, again redundancy
part0 = str.partition(' ')[0]
part2 = str.partition(' ')[2]
```

I would like to be able to do *something* like this, but cannot:

```
(part0, , part2) = str.partition(' ')
# Or:
(part0, part2)   = str.partition(' ')[0, 2]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Underscore is often used as a name for stuff you do not need, so something like this would work:

```
part0, _, part2 = str.partition(' ')
```

In this particular case, you could do this, but it isn't a pretty solution:

```
part0, part2 = str.partition(' ')[::2]
```

A more esoteric solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter
part0, part2 = itemgetter(0, 2)(str.partition(' '))
```

Comment: The underscore as variable name is really cool! What a neat trick! :-)

Comment: you cannot have that kind of 'wildcard' syntax.

Comment: Note that _ is often used by gettext, so you might not want to do that.

Comment: Thanks! The _ trick works well here and your itemgetter solution will be a fine solution for cases where I need to pick out more elements.

Comment: Why would you care if the element you don't want is labeled _ or part1 or dummy or x or whatever?  Is this just an aesthetic concern or do you think there's some inefficiency in assigning to a variable and then ignoring it?

Comment: @SilentGhost: Thanks for the correction, I had only read the PEP briefly and never used it myself.  @foosion: Its only aesthetic, the underscore "get out of the way" visually. Its is common in Python, even pylint defaults to not report variables "_" and "dummy" as unused.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, you can not take several ad hoc elements out of a list of tuple in one go.

```
part0, part1, part2 = str.partition(' ')
```

Is the way to go. Don't worry about part1, if you don't need it, you don't need it. It's common to call it "dummy" or "unused" to show that it's not used.

You CAN be ugly with:

```
part0, part2 = str.partition(' ')[::2]
```

In this specific case, but that's obfuscating and not nice towards others. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think a question I asked some time ago could help you:

[Pythonic way to get some rows of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105101/pythonic-way-to-get-some-rows-of-a-matrix)

NumPy gives you the slice syntax you want to extract various elements using a tuple or list of indices, but I don't think you'd like to convert you list of strings to a numpy.array just to extract a few elements, so maybe you could write a helper:

```
def extract(lst, *indices):
    return [lst[i] for i in indices]

item0, item2 = extract(str.partition(' '), 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `str.split(' ', 1)` instead of `str.partition(' ')`

you'll get back a list instead of a tuple, but you won't get the separator back

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
all_parts = str.partition(' ')
part0, part2 = all_parts[0], all_parts[2]
```